# ActiveAdmin: How to use multi-select in a filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, activeadmin, multi-select

A client wants to be able to filter records based on a set of objects from a one-to-one relationship (rather than just one at a time) in ActiveAdmin. I'm having trouble finding documentation regarding such functionality.

How can I present a basic multi-select filter option instead of the single-select used by default in ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple. Just add to your filter definition this option: multiple => true
example:

```
filter(:categories, {
  as: :select,
  multiple: true,
  input_html: {
    class: :select2,
    style: "width: 100%;"
  },
  label: I18n.t(:categories)
})
```